# Chromecast CAF receiver: Is there a way to skip currently playing media programatically in the CAF receiver (not from a sender)

Tags: chromecast

**Scenario**:
We load our own custom UI which counts down from 15 seconds, this UI is shown when the credits start which might have 2 minutes remaining on the video.
Once this 15 second countdown is complete, I would like to skip to the next episode in the Queue instead of watching the remaining 1m and 45s worth of credits.
Eventually we want to add a "Watch credits" button to the sender so the user has the option to watch the entire credits.

Does anyone know if the CAF Receiver currently supports skipping the currently playing media?

I tried seeking to the end of the currently playing video but it's a subpar experience as the seek takes awhile to load - it does however seek to the end and play the next episode in the queue.

Thanks!

**Update 14/10/2020**
If anyone runs into the same problem - Turns out the `getCurrentItem` in the QueueManager returns the currently playing media.
Then you can remove that item from the queue e.g.

```
const currentItem = queueManager.getCurrentItem();
if (currentItem  && currentItem.itemId) {
  queueManager.removeItems([currentItem.itemId]);
}
```

This will force the next item in the Queue to begin playing.

I would **not recommend** seeking to the end of the video.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following working for me.

It makes use of [playerManager.sendLocalMediaRequest](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.PlayerManager#sendLocalMediaRequest) method.

```
const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager();

const queueUpdateRequestData = new cast.framework.messages.QueueUpdateRequestData();
queueUpdateRequestData.jump = 1;

playerManager.sendLocalMediaRequest(queueUpdateRequestData);
```

There are also some other options you can set in the [QueueUpdateRequestData](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.messages.QueueUpdateRequestData#QueueUpdateRequestData) like setting the [currentItemId](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.messages.QueueUpdateRequestData#currentItemId) in case you already know to which item in the queue you would like to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using [QueueManager](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.QueueManager#removeItems) worked for me

```
const playerManager = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance().getPlayerManager()
const queueManager = playerManager.getQueueManager();
const currentItemId = queueManager?.getCurrentItem?.()?.itemId;
queueManager?.removeItems([currentItemId || 0]);
```